# How does MS Word handle missing font size?

Tags: microsoft-word

What happens when there is no information about font size for a run in a `.docx` document?
The short answer: MS Word treats it as 10pt. OpenOffice Writer treats it as 12pt.

However, it is unclear if MS Word *always* does this in all versions and if there exists a guarantee. Does any specification or documentation mention that it will be 10pt and that it is guaranteed to be the default in all versions? Same question could apply to the OpenOffice Writer and 12pt but I care about it a lot less.

Edit: There exists no information not just in the run, but also no info in the `Normal` style. I shall provide the fragments from the XML (since I can't seem to find a good solution to share the whole file):

```
<w:style w:type="paragraph" w:default="1" w:styleId="Normal">
    <w:name w:val="Normal"/>
    <w:qFormat/>
    <w:rsid w:val="007D13CE"/>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Palemonas" w:hAnsi="Palemonas"/>
    </w:rPr>
</w:style>
```

(the `Normal` style)

```
<w:r w:rsidRPr="00022C0B">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rStyle w:val="bzpetitas"/>
        <w:color w:val="auto"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">dkt. </w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="00022C0B">
    <w:t>vns.</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="00022C0B">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rStyle w:val="bzpaprastas2"/>
        <w:color w:val="auto"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve"> (2) </w:t>
</w:r>
```

(the run in question is the middle one reading "vns.")

Comment: I see you ask 2 questions. The text seems to indicate your care about the 2nd and the title about the 1st. I believe it would help if you could be more clear. I'm also not sure what you mean by "run".

Comment: I am asking for the documentation of how MS Word handles the case when font sizes are completely missing in a file, if such documentation exists. What should I change in the title question?

Comment: A "run" is for "run of text" in OfficeOpen XML. It is used a lot [here](http://officeopenxml.com/WPtext.php), for example.

Comment: On a second reading your questions are clear enough (It's amazing what a 2nd reading does :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug through standards and am answering my own question. If anyone has a similar question or a problem related to it, it is unlikely to be the same so I am writing up the whole process.

[[MS-OE376]: Office Implementation Information for ECMA-376 Standards Support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oe376/db9b9b72-b10b-4e7e-844c-09f88c972219)
The main standard implemented by Microsoft Office is ECMA-376. I will be referring to ECMA-376 5th edition Part 1 found [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm).
ECMA-376 defines a certain hierarchy of styles in §17.7.2. It has a nice picture of what, when, and in which order styles get applied. The text just after is slightly more relevant, though; quoting:

> - First, the document defaults are applied to all runs and paragraphs in
>     the document.
> - Next, the table style properties are applied to each table in the document, following the conditional formatting inclusions and exclusions specified per table.
> - Next, numbered item and paragraph properties are applied to each paragraph formatted with a numbering style.
> - Next, paragraph and run properties are applied to each paragraph as defined by the paragraph style.
> - Next, run properties are applied to each run with a specific character style applied.
> - Finally, we apply direct formatting (paragraph or run properties not from styles). If this direct formatting includes numbering, that numbering + the associated paragraph properties are applied.

Here, applying something overwrites what was previously applied, per property. There are more rules for "toggle properties", which are not relevant to the original question.
So, if direct formatting lacks font size, refer to the character style of the run, then refer to the paragraph and finally the document defaults, assuming no numbering nor tables involved. Also note that default styles exist for each style type (character, numbering, paragraph and table), denoted by `w:default="1"`. And also note that styles can be `basedOn` other styles.
The last step is the Document Defaults (§17.7.5) denoted by `docDefaults`. Justin Arenson already provided a good practical way to *change* it for newly created documents. For the original question, this line in the standard is crucial:

> If this element is omitted, then the document defaults shall be application-defined by the hosting application.

My interpretation: if `docDefaults` is present but just the `font-size` is missing, it is still up to the hosting application to define the font size.

I've searched through MS-OE376, which documents a lot about how the Office applications deviate from the standard, but found nothing about document defaults and this topic. It adds additional limits to a lot of things (like no commas allowed in style names or that *complex* scripts have a definite determination of size) but no default font size.

So, if it is nowhere to be found, font size is "application-defined by the hosting application", which is 10pt in practice, for MS Word, but it does not seem this is based on any standard and there are no guarantees this will be true in all versions of MS Word.

Comment: ISO/IEC 29500-1 has basically all the same info as ECMA-376 but is supposedly more closely related to MS Word.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Word stores its default values (including font size) in a file called "Normal.dotm". You can access this file by going to:

C:\Users\user name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates.

---

For modifying the default template on Windows:
1. Open a new Microsoft Word document.
2. Click the "Home" tab.
3. Click on the small box in the lower right corner of the Font category. [Picture of Font Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIBUz.png)
4. Set whatever font you would like to be the default and click "Set As Default" in the lower lefthand corner.[Picture of "Set As Default"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njSv7.png)

Follow the steps listed on this link for Mac: [Change the default settings for new documents](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-default-settings-for-new-documents-430b4132-e129-46e4-97d2-19c326352c7f#ID0EAACAAA=macOS).

To conclude, Microsoft Word bases its font-size off of the "Normal.dotm" file. You can modify the default values by following the steps above or by modifying that file directly.

---

See more information at: [Change the Normal template (Normal.dotm )](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-normal-template-normal-dotm-06de294b-d216-47f6-ab77-ccb5166f98ea).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to include images directly (too little reputation), so they're both embedded. Please let me know if you'd like more information!

Comment: Changing the global default doesn't _just_ change the global default. It actually changes the file you have open at the moment and _fixes_ the missing font size in the Normal font (if it is missing).
However, if you then open an another file with a missing font size, it is the same 10pt in Word I mention in the question and it only changes if you do the same actions on the file, setting the default font again.
You have already been big help, though. I will also update the question - the Normal font is missing size in the document, not just the run of text...

Comment: So, it almost seems like there's some kind of a "default of the default"... I don't get it.

Comment: How to create a good image that improves the question: Only capture what is needed. Windows has an inbuilt hotkey (Win + Shift + S) which executes the Snipping Tool. Any screen captured will be copied to the clipboard.

Comment: I'm still a bit unclear about what you're looking for, but thanks for more info. If you want to edit the "default of the default", then you need to modify the Normal.dotm file. See my answer for the its file path. If you do that, then it should set every new document that you make to the specifications you provided.

Comment: I guess I didn't properly specify what "missing" means in my question. I've meant _really_ missing, such that any of the actions you mention make them no longer missing and Word really wants to make sure they are never so. My question was not about editing but about existing documents and based on what they are shown.
Still, your answer was legitimately helpful in getting me on the right track! I've researched a bit more and posted an answer to my own question.